# Conditional Dynamic import of image in javascript for react

Tags: javascript, import

the usual way of importing image in react/javascript is as such:

```
import image from './img/img3.png';
...
<div>
<img src={image} />
</div>
```

I'm looking to conditionally import an image in javascript in the following manner: 
there are several images in the img folder of the format - img1.png, img2.png, img3.png, etc.. 
I'd like to calculate which image to import inside the javascript file and then subsequently import ONLY that image, something in the lines of:

```
  filename = `./img/img${num}.png`
    import(filename);
    ...
    <div>
    <img src={filename} />
    </div>
```

any idea how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. for conditional imports of image, do something like this:

```
<img src={require(`./img/${imageNum}.png`)} alt="Img" className={classes.Img} />
```